# OpenGL ES floating point supported blend modes

Tags: opengl-es

Is there any way to detect if a driver supports blending for floating point targets in OpenGL ES 2 / WebGL? On some mobile devices, glDrawElements throws GL_INVALID_OPERATION for floating point textures with blending enabled.

As no extension guarantees floating point frame buffer support, I check for it like this:

```
glGenTextures(1, &texture_test);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_test);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, opengl_es_2 ? GL_RGBA : GL_RGBA32F, 1, 1, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo_test);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo_test);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_test, 0);
fbo_test_status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
bool floating_point_supported = (fbo_test_status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE);
```

This does not seem to guarantee blending support though. I could draw something and check the error state with blending enabled but am wondering if there's a more elegant way.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL ES 2.0 doesn't natively support floating point rendering at all - it is only available on some platforms via extensions.

Floating point is only officially available in OpenGL ES 3.2.

> As no extension guarantees floating point frame buffer support

Apart from these two, sure ...

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OES_texture_float
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WEBGL_color_buffer_float

Comment: Thanks - Unfortunately I've found that those two extensions don't reliably indicate support for floating point rendering on the devices I've tested (WebGL 1, OpenGL ES 2). Also, rendering with blending enabled fails for RGBA32F targets (but works for RGBA16F targets) even on OpenGL ES 3.2 for some devices. Guess a draw call is needed to determine support or I could avoid RGBA32F for mobile devices

Comment: Generally fp32 texturing and framebuffer formats are substantially slower than narrower formats (fp16, or an wide unorm format like RGB10_A2). Personally I'd avoid it for performance reasons if nothing else ...